# Add image to the form title

Tags: java-me

I have a Form. It is scrollable 
And I need to have an image, that must always be at the top part of the scrreen.
How can I do that? 
(I can set text to the title, but not the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using lcdui Form, then you can't. If you are using LWUIT form, you can set an icon to a label then you can set this label as a title to the form via setTitleComponent(Label label).